# Taking the first letters of a name in a list of strings

Tags: java, string, loops, do-while

I am working on an assignment which states:

The do while loop should not be your first choice when writing an iterative solution. As a general rule, if you can solve the problem reasonably with a while loop then you should do that. With that being said, there is no reason why we can't practice it a little bit.

Ask the user to input a list of their favorite names. We will consider only one word names for this exercise. The user should keep inputting until "x' is entered as the name. Use a do-while loop to get all of the names. When the loop exits, output a string that contains the first initial of each name comma separated.

The problem im having with this is outputting the first letters of the name and also ending the do-while loop. here is the code I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    String first = "";

    System.out.println("Please enter a list of name: ");
    name = in.nextLine();

    do {

           name.charAt(0);
           first = first += name.charAt(0);
           name = in.nextLine();

           if(first != "") {
                first = first + ",";
           }            
    } while(name != "x");

       System.out.println("The first intial if each name is " + name);
   }
}
```

Comment: you should be outputting `first`

Comment: no need to     first = first += name.charAt(0);
The "first = " asignation is implicit with the += operator

Answer (score 0):

What are you even trying to do on the first line of the do while loop? Remember that `charAt()` returns a value; calling it without assigning the returned value to a variable would cause syntax errors. Use a while loop. Take the first input OUTSIDE the loop.

```
System.out.println("Enter a name...end with 'x'");
String first=""; //don't forget to initialize
String name = in.nextLine(); //first name taken
while(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("x")){
    first+= name.charAt(0)+", ";
    System.out.println("Enter a name...end with 'x'");
    name = in.nextLine();
}
System.out.println(first);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to compare Strings with `s1.equals(s2)` and not with `==` so instead to :

```
while(name != "x");
```

use

```
while (!name.equals("x"));
```

and instead to :

```
if(first != "") {
```

use

```
 if(first.equals("")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a list to next usages.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> names = new ArrayList();//To store entered nemes.

    System.out.println("Enter the first name. (use char 'x' to to finish)");

    String name = in.nextLine();// Get the name for first time.
    while (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
        names.add(name);// Add name to list.
        System.out.println("Enter next name. (use char 'x' to to finish)");
        name = in.nextLine();// Get the next names.
    }

    names.forEach((n) -> {// For each names get first character and print it.
        System.out.println("The first char of '" + n + "',  is: " + n.charAt(0));
    });

}
```

---

Enter the first name. (use char 'x' to to finish)
Daisy
Enter next name. (use char 'x' to to finish)
Rose
Enter next name. (use char 'x' to to finish)
Violet
Enter next name. (use char 'x' to to finish)
x
The first char of 'Daisy',  is: D
The first char of 'Rose',  is: R
The first char of 'Violet',  is: V

---

### BUILD SUCCESS

Total time: 1:18.969s
Finished at: Mon Feb 20 12:40:25 IRST 2017

### Final Memory: 8M/155M